# Conceptually simple linear-time suffix tree constructions

Tags: ds.algorithms

In 1973 Weiner gave the first linear-time construction of suffix trees. The algorithm was simplified in 1976 by McCreight, and in 1995 by Ukkonen. Nevertheless, I find Ukkonen's algorithm relatively involved conceptually.

Has there been simplifications to Ukkonen's algorithm since 1995?

Comment: Farach et el 1998. I think this is a good place to start reading: http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=Linear+Work+Suffix+Array+Construction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if there were any new results directly simplifying the construction of suffix trees. However, there has been at least [one result](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1759301) giving a very simple algorithm for constructing suffix arrays in linear time.

Note that there's more than a conceptual equivalence between these two data structures, since you can use a suffix array (with $\cal{O}(1)$ time for querying the longest common prefix) to build an equivalent suffix tree. This should be a relatively simple exercise, but I can give more details if required.

Also, for practical purposes it's even easier to build suffix arrays in $\cal{O}(n \lg n)$ time, but I guess I'm going slightly off-topic here.

Comment: Could you give a pointer to the easier way to build suffix arrays in O(N lg N) time?

Comment: Label all the suffixes of length 2^k with an integer such that the labels correspond to the order relation between suffixes. The first  step (k = 0) is obvious. To compute the labels at step k, use the labels from step k-1, and do a radix sort. This paper should be easy to understand: http://webglimpse.net/pubs/suffix.pdf

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what was mentioned ([Kärkkäinen & Sanders, 2003](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1759301)), I think you would appreciate the "newer" version by [Kärkkäinen, Sanders and Burkhard, 2006](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1217858). The algorithm basically follows the structure of Farach's algorithm. It is arguably conceptually simpler, but the real bonus is that they provide the reader with a implementation of the algorithm. It is only about 50 lines of C++, so there are indeed no hidden details.